# Add Yii2 Extension via Composer

Tags: colors, yii2, composer-php

I tried to add an extension by running the `composer` and it didn't work.
I asked about it and they told me that it will work if I install it via command line.
And I really don't know how to use the command line.

On the tutorial, they told me to run

```
$ php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widget-colorinput "*"
```

But I think that I must run something before that, to access the `composer`.
What should I do exactly?

Comment: did you install `composer` ? what happened when you executed that command in terminal ?

Comment: what errors you got?

Comment: Yes I did.
After running command it says: '$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @RaghebAlKilany remove the $ and then execute the command.

Comment: Are you in mac? Try `composer require kartik-v/yii2-widget-colorinput "*"`

Comment: Thanx @stig-js it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: [Download](https://getcomposer.org/download/) & install composer. For windows you can download `Composer-Setup.exe`.

Step 2: Move to directory when located `composer.json` file.

Step 3: Enter `php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widget-colorinput "*"` command, or modify `composer.json` file and enter `php composer.phar update` command.

```
{
    "require": {
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-colorinput": "*"
    }
}
```

Comment: C:\Users\Ragheb>cd c:\

    c:\>cd wamp\www\basic

    c:\wamp\www\basic>php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widget colorinput "*"
Could not open input file: composer.phar

Comment: In that directory you don't have file composer.phar. try enter `composer require kartik-v/yii2-widget colorinput "*"` if you install composer through `Composer-Setup.exe`.